# Are these questions about damage reduction when multiple damage types are involved duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

Recently this question was bountied:

- [What part of a multi-type damage roll is reduced by a non-type-specific effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130537)

And earlier today I found this question:

- [How does a Battle Master's Parry work with multiple damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69509)

Note that the first question is more general, asking about effects that reduce damage without specifying type and only uses Cutting Words as a go-to example. The second question is specifically about the Battle Master Fighter's Parry Maneuver, a feature which involves damage reduction and doesn't specify damage type.

Is the Parry question a duplicate of the (much newer) general question? What (if anything) should be done regarding these two questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> When are two questions considered duplicates?
>
> According to Joel Spolsky, we should [only close real duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), and according to Jeff Atwood, there are [three kinds of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/): cut-and-pastes, accidental duplicates, and borderline duplicates (requiring judgement as applied by the community).
>
> Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.
>
> Questions asking about the same aspect of the same concept, but with different examples, may or may not be considered duplicates. It depends how easy it is to figure out one example from the other. If it's only a matter of changing some numerical values or some variable names, they're duplicates. If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related.

From [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> **If you’re going to close a user’s question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate.** For example, if a user asks, “What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?” it’s OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like “What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?”

So is [How does a Battle Master's Parry work with multiple damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69509/how-does-a-battle-masters-parry-work-with-multiple-damage-types) a strict subset of [What part of a multi-type damage roll is reduced by a non-type-specific effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130537/what-part-of-a-multi-type-damage-roll-is-reduced-by-a-non-type-specific-effect)

To my mind, yes it is and should be closed as a duplicate.